# Html element binding like xaml

Tags: html, css, binding

I have a global css file, with an html element, the style code is huge, but different pages have a little different with this style, I don't want to copy multiple and only modify one or two line of the style code, is there a way to bind an html element to the css file so that it could has different version, like in xaml, we can binding a property of viewmodel to the style, so that it could dynamically load styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I don't know much about XAML. However, if you're just looking to use a global stylesheet to provide common styles, and then overide it for a few exceptions, you could just link to a specific stylesheet (lower in the html file, so it gets loaded last) containing the changes you want to make.

For example:

```
//global stylesheet
...
.classname {
color:blue;
font-family:Arial;
...
}
```

---

```
//stylesheet specific to that page
...
.classname {
color:red; //include changes
//If you don't need a style declaration changed, just leave it blank
...
}
```

Comment: But the problem of having to load a huge stylesheet remains the same.

Comment: I was under the impression that each page had only little differences to the others, with most of the declarations common. In that scenerio, a huge stylesheet would be unavoidable, but it would possible to seperate the common rules into a single cachable global stylesheet and much smaller page-specific sheets.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is dynamically load the css file that you need for that page. There are multiple ways how to do this. Since you didn't specify whether you use jQuery, you could use

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

So you could do something like:

```
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Source: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

There are multiple plugins that allow you do this through jQuery as well. You just have to search for them.